# Como escrever símbolo matemáticos no botão xml android?

Tags: android, xml

Como escrever símbolo matemáticos no botão xml Android como raiz n de x, x elevado n, se teria como fazer de modo digitado e não com imagem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar códigos unicodes para fazer isso:

Declare o código no seu `string.xml`

```
<string name="raiz"> &#8730; </string>
```

E na sua tela xml:

```
<Button
    ...
    android:text="@string/raiz"
    ...
/>
```

Aqui tem duas listas que você encontra os códigos para usar:

- [Lista 1](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php)
- [Lista 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

Comment: Valeu pela dica !